# My code is infinite looping when I want to add data in view model

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to add my data using MVNM, it can be added while not using view model. But after I add view model it keep infinite looping

Here is my my code:

```
        fabButton.setOnClickListener {
        ViewModel2.getFav(username).observe(this@desc) { favList ->
            val fav = Fav()
            fav.username = username
            fav.avatarUrl = avatarUrl
            Log.d("b",(favList.equals(favList.isNullOrEmpty()||favList[0].username!=username).toString()))
            Log.d("c",(favList).toString())
            Log.d("d", ViewModel2.getAllFav().toString())
                if (favList.isNullOrEmpty()||favList[0].username!=username) {
                    favAddUpdateViewModel.insert(fav)
                    showToast(getString(R.string.added))
                } else {
                    favAddUpdateViewModel.delete(fav)
                    showToast(getString(R.string.removed))
                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: There is no loop. Whatever causes your problem isn't in the part of the code that you provided. Can you please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Just edit your question and replace the code with the minimum of code necessary to actually reproduce the problem you experience. Curently, the code is neither minimal nor does it even produce the problem that you described.